# Door Locks problem

Tags: hyundai, door, sonata, fuse-panel, power-door-lock

my car is a Hyundai Sonata 2013 GLS, I've been having a little issue with my doors locks, it seems to try to work, I can see some movement in the rear passenger doors, the driver's locks and unlocks just fine. I've checked on YouTube and found kinda the same problem in one of the videos I checked. The guy unplugged the door locks fuse and then plugged it back in. My question is: is it wrong if i unplug the door locking system from the fuse box and then plug it back in? Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 3):

I think the reason why they are suggesting the fuse is, the part of the car which controls the locks is the body control module (BCM ... or whatever Hyundai calls it). The idea behind this is to remove the power from it (it is always on) in an attempt to reset the module. If that is what you are suggesting you want to do, there is no down side to doing this, other than my surprise if it actually works for you. You won't damage your vehicle if that is what you're wondering.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try then